# Level 3 Btec programming course java script not getting response on contact form in html and css website

Tags: javascript

I'm here to ask a question on my college course work, and my problem is with adding Java script to my HTML and CSS website I'm adding the Javascript to a contact form to ask for email, name, telephone and comment.

I'm not fully sure why this does not seem to be working, probable a stupid mistake.

Thank you for taking the time to read this and please try not to dislike this for my poor grammar/spelling.

```
<script?>
    function validateForm()
    {

    var x = document.forms["Contact.html"]["name?"].value;
    if(x== null || x == "")
    {
    alert("Name must be filled in");
    return false;
    }

    var e = document.forms["Contact.html"]["email"].value;
    if(e== null || e== "")
    {
    alert("Email must be filled in");
    returnfalse;
    }

    var t = document.forms["Contact.html"]["telephone"].value;
    if(t== null || t == "")
    {
    alert("Telephonefield must be complete");
    return false;
    }

    var c = docment.forms["Contact.html"]["comment"].value;
    if(c== null || c == "")
    {
    alter("Comment field must be complete");
    return false;
    }
    }
</script?>
```

Comment: In addition to Paul's answer you might also consider using your browser's built-in developer tools to help find errors and debug your code, I'm not sure that the first issue would have been picked up but certainly the other three would have been.

Comment: ill take that into account next time thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems I can see are:

- You're using "name?" rather than "name" in the first block
- You need a space between "return" and false in the second email block
- In your final comment block you need "document" rather than "docment"
- Also in your final comment block, you probably meant "alert" rather than "alter"

In addition, you should probably learn to indent each line of your code properly, as this greatly increases the ability of programmers that read your code later to understand it. I've added a copy of your code with these changes made below in case you need it.

Good luck on your journey to become a programmer! :D

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["Contact.html"]["name"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled in");
    return false;
  }

  var e = document.forms["Contact.html"]["email"].value;
  if (e == null || e == "") {
    alert("Email must be filled in");
    return false;
  }

  var t = document.forms["Contact.html"]["telephone"].value;
  if (t == null || t == "") {
    alert("Telephonefield must be complete");
    return false;
  }

  var c = document.forms["Contact.html"]["comment"].value;
  if (c == null || c == "") {
    alert("Comment field must be complete");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: No worries dude. I have dyslexia and remember when I spent days banging my head against the desk trying to fix problems just like this :)